# Cannot use Auth::user() in blade template in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I want to make my index page with both `guest` and `auth` functions.

When guests visit, they could try logging in; And after login, it will show the user's info such as username.

Below is what I did.

Routes are defined in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', 'CommonController@index');
Auth::routes();
```

In blade template of `index`, I used `Auth::user()` to validate authentication but failed.

```
@if(Auth::user())
    <div id="user-panel">
        <a href="" class="user-panel-button">
            New Article
        </a>
        <div class="btn-group user-panel-button">
            <a type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@else
    <a href="{{ url('login') }}" class="button">
        Login
    </a>
@endif
```

Every time I logged in successfully, it will still show `login` button instead of user name button, after I REFRESH the index page.

I have checked session information, once I refreshed the page, the `login_web_xxxxxxxxxxx` session will be disappeared.

Furthermore, When I use Laravel default path for auth `/home`, it worked. Username could always be presented whatever how many times you refresh the page.

How should I fix this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: does your storage folder have right permissions?

Comment: You're calling `Auth::logout()`, which actually logs the user out, no button click needed.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am not calling ```Auth::logout()``` here, and the permission of storage folder is right, since the default page of path ```home``` in ```HomeController``` is worked. Whatever how many times I refresh the page, the ```login_web_xxx``` session is available.

Comment: `<li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Logout</a></li>` <-- Right there. This logs the user out, it does not create a link for them to do so.

Comment: Ah, I see. I know how to do right. Thanks, @aynber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

For log out, it is better to be codes as below, which is provided by official `resources/view/layouts/app.php`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            Logout
        </a>

        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

For Laravel 5.4 you can use:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    // The user is authenticated...
@else
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endif
```

For Laravel 5.5 and above:

```
@auth
    // The user is authenticated...
@endauth

@guest
    // The user is not authenticated...
@endguest
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `routes/web.php` file as

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  Route::get('/', 'CommonController@index');
  Auth::routes();
}
```

Now to check auth in your blade template, you can use

```
@if(\Auth::check())
  ....
  ....
@else
  ....
  ....
@endif
```

Comment: I know what is wrong here, which @aynber mentioned in the comments. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use the full class path of Auth in blade file like this

```
@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
 // code here
@endif
```